# Ubuntu-64 prompt ain't showing my username

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu-64 prompt ain't showing my username

[image]

instead this is what it is showing

Comment: "Toto, I've a feeling we're not in Ubuntu anymore..."

Comment: Anyway, looks like Virtualbox is playing up... Try the steps here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326956/virtualbox-guest-suddenly-boots-only-into-uefi-interactive-shell

Comment: What happens when you restart Virtual Box (before trying to start Ubuntu). Do you get the correct screen?

Answer (score 0):

That's not Ubuntu, but an EFI shell. VirtualBox boots into the EFI shell when there are no viable boot targets. (Which is not uncommon in VBox because of its flaky EFI implementation which doesn't persist boot entries).

There are a few paths from there:

- You can add the boot entry to VM's EFI config. You can access it on boot by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>. Then you can add the entry under *Boot maintenance* section. The loader is called `grubx64.efi` is my memory serves and should be located under `\EFI\ubuntu` on the first partition. *You'll have to do this again on each boot.*
- You could play with the ESP partition and add a default loader at `EFI/boot/bootx64.efi`. This would require some GRUB or syslinux knowledge.
- Newer Ubuntu versions (18.04 and up) create a default loader themselves, so they aren't affected by this issue, so installing a newer version of Ubuntu would be an option.
- For older Ubuntu versions I'd recommend disabling EFI in favor of BIOS, which has more reliable VirtualBox implementation. This can be done in VM settings, but will require some manual adjustments to the OS. Specifically, you'll have to repurpose the ESP to a bootstrap partition for GRUB and install GRUB packages with BIOS support (you have EFI support installed currently).

Out of these, upgrading to 18.04 is the most beginner-friendly option and you should do that anyway, because older versions are either already unsupported or nearing their EOL.